# converting a number of lists into single dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have a number of seperate lists:

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
```

Now I would like to convert these three separate lists into a dict such as this:

```
{1:4,7, 2:5,8, 3:6,9}
```

Where each of the elements in the first list become the 'keys' and the all the elements under become the 'values' (or is it the otherway around?)...

now I understand such a thing could be achieved by what is known as the grouper recipe (itertools, etc)... if it were the case the lists were like this:

```
([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
```

But it is not like that... I cant wrap my head around trying to do this with separate lists.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [dictionary comprehension](http://www.diveinto.org/python3/comprehensions.html#dictionarycomprehension) like this

```
l1, l2, l3 = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]
data = [l1, l2, l3]
print {k:[v1, v2] for k, v1, v2 in zip(*data)}
```

**Output**

```
{1: [4, 7], 2: [5, 8], 3: [6, 9]}
```

**Edit:** If the lists are prepared in a loop, `data` can be composed with list comprehension like this

```
data = [[j for j in range(i * 3, i * 3 + 3)] for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... what does v1, v2 mean?

Comment: @user3029969 `k`, `v1` and `v2` will have the unpacked values from each and every sublist. For example, in the first iteration, `k`, `v1` and `v2` will have 1, 2, 3 respectively.

Comment: also will this work for any arbitrary number of lists with arbitrary number of elements in them? Dont the k,v1,v2 limit that then? EDIT: okay I just saw gnibbler's answer

Comment: @user3029969 It is possible, instead of unpacking, we can use gnibbler's or inspectorG4dget's solution

Comment: humm.. okay, so what if I the lists that I generate are from a loop .. and they are not labled as l1, l2, l3... how can I lable them then?

Comment: @user3029969 I have shown an example in the answer, to demonstrate how we can generate the data in the loop, with list comprehension. Please check.

Comment: the i*3, i*3 + 3... what does this part exactly do?

Comment: @user3029969 Thats the range of numbers to be generated. From `i * 3` to `i * 3 + 3` :)

Comment: oh I see :p  .. but how could we convert that to an arbitrary form... sorry if I am asking too many silly questions... I am pretty new to programming myself. :D

Answer (score 4):

Python3 has new and improved unpacking syntax:

```
>>> L1
[1, 2, 3]
>>> L2
[4, 5, 6]
>>> L3
[7, 8, 9]
>>> data = [L1,L2,L3]
>>> {k:v for k, *v in zip(*data)}
{1: [4, 7], 2: [5, 8], 3: [6, 9]}
```

However, this is not available in python2.x, so you'd have to go with [@thefourtheye's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20184773/198633) on that front

Answer (score 2):

The general form of @thefourtheye's answer - ie. works with more than 3 lists

```
print {i[0]:i[1:] for i in zip(*data)}
```

and a version that doesn't use a dict comprehension (unpacking works similar to the Python3 verison)

```
print dict(map(lambda k, *v: (k, v), *data))
```

Comment: So the first version will work with an arbitrary amount of lists with arbitrary amounts of elements in them?

Comment: @user3029969, Either version will

Comment: FWIW, this will create  a dictionary with `tuple`s for values.  That could be easily be fixed if necessary...

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
def change(*L):
    res = collections.defaultdict(list)
    T = list(zip(*L[1:]))
for i, key in enumerate(L[0]):
    res[key] = T[i]
    return res

L1 = [1,  2,  3,  10]
L2 = [4,  5,  6,  11]
L3 = [7,  8,  9,  12]
L4 = [13, 14, 15, 16]
print(change(L1, L2, L3, L4))
```

The output is: `{1: (4, 7, 13), 2: (5, 8, 14), 3: (6, 9, 15), 10: (11, 12, 16)})`

Please use this code, you can handle any number of list.